# Reverse list of lists

Tags: list, prolog, reverse

I have a problem with my prolog code. I need to reverse all atomic elements of list.

Example: [1,2,[3,4]] -> [[4,3],2,1]

My solution:

```
myReverse([], []).
myReverse([H|T], X) :- myReverse(T, RT), myAppend(RT, H, X).
```

But it only gives me: [[3,4],2,1]
I think, I need to use is_list function and recursive call list if it's not atomic... but I am stuck... do you guys know how to write it?

Comment: What's `spoj/3`? I'm familiar with SPhere Online Judge, but when it comes to Prolog, I'm lost...

Comment: I have renamed it to myAppend, function join two lists and save result to X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly. Consider this solution:

```
myReverse([], []) :- !.

myReverse([H|T], X) :-
    !,
    myReverse(H, NewH),
    myReverse(T, NewT),
    append(NewT, [NewH], X).

myReverse(X, X).
```

The first clause is the base case, which includes a cut (`!`) to exclude choices left because of the last clause.

The second clause reverses the head `H`, which may be an atom or a list. If `H` is an atom, the recursive subgoal after the cut evaluates with the last clause, and atoms are passed through unchanged. If `H` is a list, it is evaluated with the second clause and all elements are reversed. The next subgoal does the same with the remainder of the list (the tail, `T`), then are finally concatenated using the built-in `append/3`. Note that the new head element `NewH` is singular, so needs to be added to a singleton list structure as `[NewH]` as per the definition of `append/3` which operates on lists.

The last clause passes all other things (i.e., atoms, numbers, etc. - anything that isn't a list or a variable) through unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

```
revall(L, Y) :-
    revall(L, [], Y).
revall([], Y, Y).
revall([H|T], T2, Y) :-
    is_list(H),!,
    revall(H, Hr),
    revall(T, [Hr|T2], Y).
revall([H|T], T2, Y) :-
    revall(T, [H|T2], Y).
```

here without append

Comment: +1: This is a nice accumulator version and would use less stack space as the version I proposed (which isn't tail recursive). You could even replace the `is_list/1` call (and leave the cut) if you used pattern-matching instead by changing `H` to `[H|Hs]` throughout the second clause of `revall/3`, then no built-ins would be needed at all.